# Java Thread.sleep long or int?

Tags: java, sleep, numeric, literals

`Thread.sleep` takes a `long` as an argument for milliseconds.  But numeric literals are treated as integers unless specified otherwise with the letter notation like `1000L`.  So why is this valid code?

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Integers can be promoted to a wider integer type.  `long big = 2;` is valid code, the 2 is "widened" silently to a long.

Comment: @markspace why did you comment instead of answer?  If you answered I would accept your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Because `int` can be promoted to `long`.

`long` is bigger (more bits) than `int` and so `int` can be converted to `long` without any loss of data. Going the other way may have problems because data could be lost - hence that would be an error.

Answer (score 3):

It's a valid widening conversion, see also [JLS-5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) which says *in part*

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the *widening primitive conversions:*
>
> - `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`